# Dynamic input field being rendered after the </form> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is weird but I have a button id #fusk on click of which I am adding some dynamic elements as such

```
$('#imgc').append(
  "<div class='divi'>" +
  "<input type='hidden' name='"+i+"' value='"+e.target.result+"'  />" +
  "<div class='remove_f' onClick='remove_f()'>" +
  "<a href='#'><i class='glyphicon-circle_remove icon_margin'></i></a>" + 
  "</div><img style='float:left' class='oni_wh' src='"+e.target.result+"'/></div>");
```

the elements are being added inside a form

```
<form method="post" id="frmi" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
  <div class="right_btn_holder_">
    <label id="add_i" for="fusk" id="fuskb" class="btn btn-success">
      <i class="glyphicon-circle_plus icon_margin"></i>
    </label>

    <button id="uim" type="submit" id="remove_data" class="btn btn-danger">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload icon_upload"></i><?php echo strings("upload"); ?>
    </button>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box-content nopadding">
    <div class="tab-content padding tab-content-inline tab-content-bottom">
      <div class="control-group">
        <label  class="control-label"><?php echo strings("offer_titl"); ?></label>
        <div class="controls">
          <input maxlength="50" type="text"  name="on" placeholder="<?php echo strings("titl");?>"/>        
        </div>
      </div>
      <input multiple accept="image/x-png,image/jpeg" id="fusk" type="file" name="photo[]" style="display: none;">

      <div id="imgc" class="control-group">

      </div>    
</form>
```

But when the elements are added is see the elements are appearing after `</form>` tag thus no data is being sent

Comment: You haven't accidently assigned the same id  to two elements, right ?

Comment: You have an extra `</div>` just before `<div class="box-content nopadding">`. That will be messing up your markup. Get a better editor that can highlight these trivial mistakes

Comment: You also have unclosed `<div>` elements further down

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Form should have Proper starting and closing tags.

There are lots of divs which not closing and some of them closed without starting. That's why the issue is occurring.

```
<div id="imgc" class="control-group">
```

Jquery really can't finding closing div that's why `Append` not working properly.

Answer (score 0):

`<label>` has two id's, remove one. It's probably breaking something in your code.

Comment: id is not an issue, have checked that properly